# Es posible introducir un valor, volver con return y que no se pierda?

Tags: java, lista

Bueno básicamente hago una especie de aplicación para una biblioteca donde se navega por un menú, todo se introduce en listas separadas, aún no está listo pero me surge el siguiente problema, estoy introduciendo datos y al final de ello, uso el método return para volver al menú, en ese momento se pierde la información que es guardada. Es posible que no se pierda esta información y retornar?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String menuinicio=" ";
        System.out.println(menu(menuinicio));       
    }

public static String menu(String menu) {
    Scanner d = new Scanner (System.in) ;       
    String menuinicio= 
        "********Menu********** \r\n"+
        " Introduce un dato: \r\n"+
        "1-.Insertar persona \r\n" + 
        "2.-Insertar Libro \r\n" + 
        "3.-Prestar libro \r\n" + 
        "4-Mostrar lista de personas registradas \r\n" + 
        "5.-Mostrar lista de libros registrados \r\n" + 
        "6.-Mostrar lista de personas que tiene al menos un libro de la biblioteca \r\n" + 
        "7.-Mostrar lista de ficha de préstamos \r\n" + 
        "8.-Mostrar libros prestados a una persona: insertar código de persona \r\n" + 
        "9.-Mostrar datos de ficha de préstamo: insertar código de ficha ";


    System.out.println(menuinicio);

//Lista Libros
    List <String> Listalibros= new LinkedList <String>();

    Listalibros.add("Caperucita Roja"+" "+ "2677893"+" "+"Ejemplo1 Mendoza"+" "+ "Infantil"+" "+ "27"+" "+ "no");
    Listalibros.add("Los tres cerditos"+" "+ "2677894"+" "+ "Ejemplo2 Escudero"+" "+ "Infantil"+" "+ "30"+" "+ "no");


//opciones

if(opcion==2) {


                Listalibros.add( (pregunta6(nombrel)+" "+ pregunta7(code)+" "+ pregunta8(autor)+" " +pregunta9(genero)+" "+pregunta10(paginas)+" "+ pregunta11(estado)));

                System.out.println("Se ha introducido con exito.");
                System.out.println(Listalibros);
                Scanner da = new Scanner (System.in) ;                              
                System.out.println("Pulse Enter para volver al menu");  
                volver=da.nextLine();           

                return menu(menu);
            }
// Preguntas libro

public static String pregunta6(String opcion1l) {   

    String nombrel;     
    Scanner d = new Scanner (System.in) ;                               
    System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del libro");   
    nombrel=d.nextLine();                                                           
    return nombrel;         
}
public static String pregunta7(String opcionc) {    

    String code;        
    Scanner d = new Scanner (System.in) ;                               
    System.out.println("Introduzca el codigo del libro");   
    code=d.nextLine();

    if (code.matches("[0-9]*" )) {
        while (code.length()==9) {
            return code;
        }           
        System.out.println("Debe contener 9 Numeros");
            return pregunta7(code);
    }else {
        System.out.println("No es un valor valido");
        return pregunta7(code);
    }
}
public static String pregunta8(String opciona) {    

    String autor;       
    Scanner d = new Scanner (System.in) ;                               
    System.out.println("Introduzca el autor del libro");    
    autor=d.nextLine();     
    if(autor.matches("[0-9]*")) {
        System.out.println("Debe introducir una letra");
        return pregunta8(autor);    
    }
    return autor;       
}
public static String pregunta9(String opciona) {    

    String genero;      
    Scanner d = new Scanner (System.in) ;                               
    System.out.println("Introduzca el genero del libro");   
    genero=d.nextLine();    
    if(genero.matches("[0-9]*")) {
        System.out.println("Debe introducir una letra");
        return pregunta9(genero);   
    }   
    return genero;  
}
public static String pregunta10(String opciona) {   

    String paginas;     
    Scanner d = new Scanner (System.in) ;                               
    System.out.println("Introduzca las paginas del libro"); 
    paginas=d.nextLine();
    if(paginas.matches("[0-9]*")) { 
        return paginas; 
    }
    System.out.println("Debe introducir un número");
    return pregunta10(paginas); 
}
public static String pregunta11(String opciona) {   

    String estado;  
    String si="si", no="no";
    Scanner d = new Scanner (System.in) ;                               
    System.out.println("¿Está realizando un prestamo del libro?");      
    estado=d.nextLine();                
    if(estado==si) {
        estado="si";
        System.out.println("No es una respuesta valida");
        return pregunta11(estado);  
    }
    if(estado==no) {
        estado="no";
        System.out.println("No es una respuesta valida");
        return pregunta11(estado);  
    }
    if(estado!=no && estado!=si) {  
    return estado;  
    }   
    return estado;  
}
```

Solo he colocado el ejemplo de lo que sería con libros y lo que llevo, es un ejercicio donde me piden solo usar list. Por ello me limito a eso.

EDIT: me habian comentado otros compañeros que lo hicieron con Switch, de no funcionar cambiaría el código pero primero quiero ver si es posible como lo estaba haciendo.

Comment: Para resolver tu problema te recomiendo volver a un manual de java y revisar el tema de las variables, dónde se definen, cómo se definen, dónde se usan y cuándo se destruyen. Una variable definida dentro de una función se destruye automáticamente cuando termine la función. Una definida en una clase se destruye cuando se destruya el objeto de esa clase. Te recomiendo también  revisar el tema de static y para qué se usa.

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas un `do{} while();` puedes retornar al menú sin perder los datos ya guardados.

PD: Te recomiendo declarar un objeto Scanner como variable de `instanza(` y utilizarlo en cualquier método de la clase) haría mas legible tu código.

Aqui un ejemplo:

```
public class Esercizio2{
Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main (String [] args)
{

    int a,b = 0;
    System.out.println("Inserici numero: ");
    a = x.nextInt();
    do{

        a=a/10;
        b++;
    }
    while (a!=0);

    System.out.println("Il numero e formato da " + b + " cifre");

}
```

}

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso es lo que estoy haciendo ahora. Ahora si funciona.

Comment: @CarlosAquino En primer lugar, te doy la bienvenida al sitio. Si esta respuesta te ha solucionado el problema, considera hacer click en el botón de aceptar respuesta y votarla como positivo.

Comment: @Jane, también te doy la bienvenida al sitio. Aunque con una respuesta breve has ayudado al OP, podrías considerar editar la respuesta para hacerla más completa por ejemplo añadiendo código de ejemplo y referencias a las fuentes que te has basado. De esa manera no solo ayudas a la persona que formula la pregunta sino a las personas que lean esta pregunta en el futuro.